# FCM very slow and unreliable when sending to a group of recipients through Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the following Function that:

1. Listens for document (text message) creation
2. Grab IDs of members of a group chat
3. Get the FCM Tokens for each member
4. With a for-loop, send messages to group members

```js
exports.sendChatMessage = functions.firestore
  .document("chats/{mealID}/messages/{messageID}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const data = snap.data();
    const mealID = context.params.mealID;
    const senderID = data.senderID;
    const senderName = data.senderName;
    const messageContent = data.content;

    var docRef = db.collection("chats").doc(mealID);
    docRef
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          const docData = doc.data();
          const mealName = docData.name;
          const userStatus = docData.userStatus;
          var users = docData.to;
          var eligibleUsers = users.filter(
            (user) => userStatus[user] == "accepted"
          );
          eligibleUsers.push(docData.from);

          // get fcmTokens from eligibleUsers and send the messagme
          db.collection("users")
            .where("uid", "in", eligibleUsers)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
              var fcmTokens = [];
              var thumbnailPicURL = "";
              // get thumbnailpic of the sender and collect fcmTokens
              snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                if (doc.data().uid == senderID) {
                  thumbnailPicURL =
                    doc.data().thumbnailPicURL == null
                      ? "https://i.imgur.com/8wSudUk.png"
                      : doc.data().thumbnailPicURL;
                } else {
                  fcmTokens.push(doc.data().fcmToken);
                }
              });

              // send the message fcmTokens
              fcmTokens.forEach((token) => {
                if (token != "") {
                  const fcmMessage = {
                    message: {
                      token: token,
                      notification: {
                        title: mealName,
                        body: senderName + ": " + messageContent,
                        image: thumbnailPicURL,
                      },
                      apns: {
                        payload: {
                          aps: {
                            category: "MESSAGE_RECEIVED",
                          },
                          MEAL_ID: mealID,
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  };
                  tokenManger.sendFcmMessage(fcmMessage);
                }
              });
              return true;
            });
        } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
          return false;
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        return false;
      });
    return true;
  });
```

My send function comes from a helper file that uses the [HTTP V1 protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server) to build the send-request:

```js
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const https = require("https");
const MESSAGING_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";
const SCOPES = [MESSAGING_SCOPE];
const PROJECT_ID = MY_PROJECT_ID;
const HOST = "fcm.googleapis.com";
const PATH = "/v1/projects/" + PROJECT_ID + "/messages:send";

exports.getAccessToken = () => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const key = require("./service-account.json");
    var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
      key.client_email,
      null,
      key.private_key,
      SCOPES,
      null
    );
    jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(tokens.access_token);
    });
  });
};

//send message
exports.sendFcmMessage = (fcmMessage) => {
  this.getAccessToken().then(function (accessToken) {
    var options = {
      hostname: HOST,
      path: PATH,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
      },
      // … plus the body of your notification or data message
    };
    var request = https.request(options, function (resp) {
      resp.setEncoding("utf8");
      resp.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log("Message sent to Firebase for delivery, response:");
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
    request.on("error", function (err) {
      console.log("Unable to send message to Firebase");
      console.log(err);
    });
    request.write(JSON.stringify(fcmMessage));
    request.end();
  });
};
```

It worked all fine in the emulator but once deployed, there're significant delays (~3 mins):

[image: Cloud Function console output]

I also noticed that the console says the cloud function finishes execution BEFORE `sendFcmMessage` logs success messages.

I did some research online, it appears that it might have something to do with the usage of `Promise` but I wasn't sure if that's the sole reason or it has something to do with my for-loop.

Comment: I'll have to come back to this later because your question is code heavy, but basically you are creating "floating promises" or starting other asynchronous tasks (like in `sendFcmMessage`) where you aren't returning a promise. Because these promises haven't been properly chained, your Cloud Function is being throttled down before it's finished doing what it needs to. Fix the promise chains and you'll see performance pick up. The local emulators don't emulate the aggressive instance management system that the production servers use which is why you don't see the same performance drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

To summarize the issue, you are creating "floating promises" or starting other asynchronous tasks (like in `sendFcmMessage`) where you aren't returning a promise because they use callbacks instead.

In a deployed function, as soon as the function returns its result or the Promise chain resolves, **all further actions should be treated as if they will never be executed** [as documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/tips#do_not_start_background_activities). An "inactive" function might be terminated at any time, is severely throttled and any network calls you make (like setting data in database or calling out to FCM) may never be executed.

An indicator that you haven't properly chained the promises is when you see the function completion log message ("Function execution took...") before other messages you are logging. When you see this, you need to look at the code you are running and confirm whether you have any "floating promises" or are using callback-based APIs. Once you have changed the callback-based APIs to use promises and then made sure they are all chained together properly, you should see a significant boost in performance.

### The fixes

#### Sending the message data to FCM

In your `tokenManger` file, `getAccessToken()` could be reworked slightly and `sendFcmMessage` should be converted to return a `Promise`:

```js
exports.getAccessToken = () => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const key = require("./service-account.json");
    const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
      key.client_email,
      null,
      key.private_key,
      SCOPES,
      null
    );
    jwtClient.authorize(
      (err, tokens) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(tokens.access_token)
    );
  });
};

//send message
exports.sendFcmMessage = (fcmMessage) => {
  // CHANGED: return the Promise
  return this.getAccessToken().then(function (accessToken) {
    const options = {
      hostname: HOST,
      path: PATH,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
      },
      // … plus the body of your notification or data message
    };
    // CHANGED: convert to Promise:
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const request = https.request(options, (resp) => {
        resp.setEncoding("utf8");
        resp.on("data", resolve);
        resp.on("error", reject);
      });
      request.on("error", reject);
      request.write(JSON.stringify(fcmMessage));
      request.end();
    });
  });
};
```

However, the above code was built for `googleapis ^52.1.0` and `google-auth-library ^6.0.3`. The modern versions of these modules are `v92.0.0` and `v7.11.0` respectively. This means you should really update the code to use these later versions like so:

```js
// Import JWT module directly
const { JWT } = require('google-auth-library');
// FIREBASE_CONFIG is a JSON string available in Cloud Functions
const PROJECT_ID = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId;
const FCM_ENDPOINT = `https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/messages:send`;
const FCM_SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"];

exports.sendFcmMessage = (fcmMessage) => {
  const key = require("./service-account.json"); // consider moving outside of function (so it throws an error during deployment if its missing)
  const client = new JWT({
    email: key.client_email,
    key: key.private_key,
    scopes: FCM_SCOPES
  });
  return client.request({ // <-- this uses `gaxios`, Google's fork of `axios` built for Promise-based APIs
    url: FCM_ENDPOINT,
    method: "POST",
    data: fcmMessage
  });
}
```

Better yet, just use the [messaging APIs provided by the Firebase Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) that handle the details for you. Just feed it the message and tokens as needed.

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase-admin/messaging";

initializeApp(); // initializes using default credentials provided by Cloud Functions
const fcm = getMessaging();

fcm.send(message) // send to one (uses the given token)
fcm.sendAll(messagesArr) // send to many at once (each message uses the given token)
fcm.sendMulticast(message) // send to many at once (uses a `tokens` array instead of `token`)
```

#### The Cloud Function

Updating the main Cloud Function, you'd get:

```js
exports.sendChatMessage = functions.firestore
  .document("chats/{mealID}/messages/{messageID}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const mealID = context.params.mealID;
    const { senderID, senderName, content: messageContent } = snap.data();

    const docRef = db.collection("chats").doc(mealID);
    
    /* --> */ return docRef
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (!doc.exists) { // CHANGED: Fail fast and avoid else statements
          console.log(`Could not find "chat:${mealID}"!`);
          return false;
        }

        const { userStatus, to: users, name: mealName, from: fromUser } = doc.data();
        const eligibleUsers = users.filter(
          (user) => userStatus[user] == "accepted"
        );
        eligibleUsers.push(fromUser);

        // get fcmTokens from eligibleUsers and send the message
        /* --> */ return db.collection("users")
          .where("uid", "in", eligibleUsers) // WARNING: This will only work for up to 10 users! You'll need to break it up into chunks of 10 if there are more.
          .get()
          .then(async (snapshot) => {
            const fcmTokens = [];
            let thumbnailPicURL = "";
            // get thumbnailpic of the sender and collect fcmTokens
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              if (doc.get("uid") == senderID) {
                thumbnailPicURL = doc.get("thumbnailPicURL"); // update with given thumbnail pic
              } else {
                fcmTokens.push(doc.get("fcmToken"));
              }
            });

            const baseMessage = {
              notification: {
                title: mealName,
                body: senderName + ": " + messageContent,
                image: thumbnailPicURL || "https://i.imgur.com/8wSudUk.png", // CHANGED: specified fallback image here
              },
              apns: {
                payload: {
                  aps: {
                    category: "MESSAGE_RECEIVED",
                  },
                  MEAL_ID: mealID,
                },
              }
            }

            // log error if fcmTokens empty?

            // ----- OPTION 1 -----
            // send the message to each fcmToken
            const messagePromises = fcmTokens.map((token) => {
              if (!token) // handle "" and undefined
                return; // skip
              
              /* --> */ return tokenManger
                .sendFcmMessage({
                  message: { ...baseMessage, token }
                })
                .catch((err) => { // catch the error here, so as many notifications are sent out as possible
                  console.error(`Failed to send message to "fcm:${token}"`, err);
                })
            });

            await Promise.all(messagePromises); // wait for all messages to be sent out
            // --------------------
            
            // ----- OPTION 2 -----
            // send the message to each fcmToken
            await getMessaging().sendAll(
              fcmTokens.map((token) => ({ ...baseMessage, token }))
            );
            // --------------------

            return true;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error sending messages:", error);
            return false;
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        return false;
      });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I found out that the culprit is my queries to `db`. Like @samthecodingman commented, I was creating floating Promises.

Originally, I have codes like:

```js
db.collection("users")
            .where("uid", "in", eligibleUsers)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {...}
```

All I needed to do is to return that call:

```js
return db.collection("users")
            .where("uid", "in", eligibleUsers)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {...}
```

Although it's still not instant delivery, it's much faster now.